# How to get the MAC address of remote raspberry using his ip address using python code

Tags: python-3.x, networking, raspberry-pi3, mac-address

I am developing the ad-hoc network. I want to get MAC address of remote raspberry using his IP address. 
I am doing this code 
import sys,os
os.system ('sudo arp -n 115.0.0.2') 
i am getting all things like hWthype, name of device and Flags Mask, HWaddress but i need only HWaddress 
Can i body help me how I can extract only MAC address of remote raspberry using python code instead of cmd command?

Comment: MAC addresses are only ever seen on the network local to the host with the MAC address. You would need some process on the remote network to capture and send you a MAC address from a remote network. Of course, the remote MAC address is of no use on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Grep command an catch MAC address with a regular expression to retrieve the line of the mac address.
Then use cut command to select only the address.
Post ifconfig output so we can help you better